# Hadoop:datanode not connecting to namenode on localhost:50070 cluster summary shows 0

Tags: hadoop

logs

```
2014-05-12 16:41:26,773 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC: Server at     namenode/192.168.12.196:10001 not available yet, Zzzzz...
2014-05-12 16:41:28,777 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: namenode/192.168.12.196:10001. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
```

core site xml....

```xml
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/usr/local/hadoop/tmp</value>
        <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://user@namenode:10001</value>

    </property>
</configuration>
```

i put in etc/hosts

```
192.168.12.196   namenode
```

in masters

```
user@namenode
```

in slaves

```
localhost
```

and my namenode is on user@192.168.12.196
if i do jps on all node it shows datanode namenode job/tasktracker working fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to change to localhost into namenode in slaves and masters file and restart hadoop once it will work fine.

Comment: that's my datanode configuration. I put <user>@192.168.12.196 in slave file but its not working can u please tell me what should be in slaves file of datanode and namenode. I am using all nodes like <user>@<iP address> is it right way to refer nodes in Hadoop

Comment: just keep hostname only in slaves and masters files then it will work fine. you just use hostname only.

Comment: just change into namenode in slaves and masters files.

Comment: Thanks for your Comment
if i put hostname  in slaves of namenode it runs datanode and namenode on same node 
configuration of my masters and slave are hereafter
on namenode'masters
    '<user>@namenode'    

on namenode'master
    'hdname1@data1  (data1 belong to ip of node and hdname1 is user)'
    'hdname2@data2'

on datanode' masters
'<user>@namenode'

on datanode's slaves
'hdname1@data1'

Comment: First tell me your using single node or multe nodes.

Comment: multi nodes cluster...
name node.. user@namenode
datanode... hdname1@data1
datanode... hdname2@data2

Comment: how can i check that "user@namenode:10001" port is accessible from datanode (if i m doing jps on all node it look fine)

Comment: it will run datanode into data1, data2 also

Comment: You can get total 3 datanode and one namenode will run.

Comment: example of slaves file: namenode

Comment: and what should be in slaves of "data1" and "data2",
and what should be fs.defalt.name in core-site.xml of Data1 and 2 >>
<value>hdfs://namenode:10001</value>
  OR <value>hdfs://user@namenode:10001</value>

Comment: You should use <value>hdfs://namenode:10001</value>  this only in core-site.xml

Comment: data1 data2 is slavenodes like datanodes

Comment: you can check namenode in browser namenode:50070

Comment: and what entries should be in slaves of data1 and data2

Comment: in this way data1 data2 is datanodes if want to use that you need to add that you don't want that just use namenode in slaves file this time namenode only datanode.

Comment: i am using "namenode" as name node not as datanode, i put user@namenode in slaves on datanodes but its not working,on namenode localhost:50070 it shows live node 0,    is there any permission issue on port :10001

Comment: namenode:50070 you need use

Comment: add that slaves file and masters file to here

Comment: now i have another issue  ... if i click on live node it shows the list of my two datanode, further if i click on any node it shows "server not found"

Comment: Same way check jps in all nodes,

Answer (score 0):

> for better view

Thanks for your Comment
if i put hostname  in slaves of namenode it runs datanode and namenode on same node 
configuration of my masters and slave are hereafter,
on **namenode's masters**

```
'user@namenode'
```

**on namenode'master**

```
hdname1@data1  (data1 belong to ip of node and hdname1 is user)
hdname2@data2
```

**on datanode's masters**

```
user@namenode
```

**on datanode's slaves**

```
hdname1@data1
```